# ActionBar Appearing over edittext in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

[double action bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ8cF.png)

ActionBar is covering more space.It seems it is appearing twice.I have extended AppCompatActivity.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

and used parent theme as

Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

My Activity is:

Enter Name:

### Name

### Email

Choose a password:

### Password

But Action Bar has covered TextView "Entername" and the edittext "Name"

Comment: If that is the case why don't u use the `layout_margin` to nudge the edit text away from the action bar

Comment: look if in your xml you have toolbar, if yes, delete it and run on emulator. I maightly be doubled

Comment: Could you please add your layout xml file to your question?